# student and faculty code are not working only adminstration code in working in switch case?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

```
<?php
include("dbh.php");
session_start();

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    // username and password sent from form 

    $username = strtoupper($_POST['username']);
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    echo $_POST['category'];

    $type = $_POST['category'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE upper(username) = '$username' and password = '$password' and type ='$type'";

    $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
    $row    = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $active = (isset($row['active']));

    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    // If result matched $username and $password, table row must be 1 row

    /*  if($count == 1) {
    // session_register("username");

    $_SESSION["login_user"] = $username;
    setcookie("username1", $username, time()+3600, "/","", 0);
```

//switch only administration case is working not student and faculty//
        switch ($type) {
            case 'administration':
                header("location: admindashboard.php");
                break;
            case 'faculty':
                header("location: admindashboard.php");
                break;
            case 'Student':
                header("location: Studentdashboard.php");
                echo $type;
                echo ("aaaaa");
                break;
        }
    }

Comment: When you were asking your question, there was a big orange **How to Format** box to the right of the text area with useful information in it. There was also an entire toolbar of formatting aids. And a **[?]** button giving formatting help. *And* a preview area located between the text area and the Post Your Question button (so that you'd have to scroll past it to find the button, to encourage you to look at it) showing what your post would look like when posted. Making your post clear, and demonstrating that you took the time to do so, improves your chances of getting good answers.

Comment: *(I've fixed it for you on this occasion.)* Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please have a look at PHP comparison operators. Using `=` inside an IF expression does assignment, no comparison. Your code is also vulnerable to SQL injection

Comment: Your switch looks fine. How is the post data coming through?

Comment: The switch case is fine. Please update the question with a sample input received for *_POST* data for the failure scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"if ($type='administration') {" is not correct "elseif ($type='faculty') {" is also wrong:

```
if ($type=='administration') { 
...
 elseif ($type=='faculty') {
```

that's it. See the number of '='s in each statement.

Comment: if else statement is in comment , switch statement is in code ... please tell in switch..... and i talk about if statement if ($type='administration') {

    header("location: admindashboard.php");
    } this working but next else part is not working